# Need help in migrating CruiseControl.Net to Jenkins for MSTest Automation Projects

Tags: jenkins, mstest, cruisecontrol.net, runner, jenkins-mstest

Currently in our company we are executing tests from CCNet (in Automation VM) by specifying different build arguments, however I feel it is now best to migrate to better automation server which is Jenkins

I am new to Jenkins world however I started installing the jenkins (though had issue in starting the Jenkins Service, later found it was due to JDK version issue)

But now I have installed all the needed plugins(GIT - for gitlab repository, MSBuild and MStest)

But I do not know how do I specify build arguments in Jenkins the way we do it in CCNet.config files

Here is the CCNet Config File that we use to Force the build

```
  <project name="AutoTests - Payments" queue="Q13">
 <triggers>
     <!--<scheduleTrigger time="03:30" buildCondition="ForceBuild" name="Scheduled" />-->
  </triggers>
   <workingDirectory>D:\GIT-TA</workingDirectory>
  <artifactDirectory>D:\DEV\deploy\AutomatedTest\BuildLogs\BasicTests.Payments</artifactDirectory>
  <category>AutomatedTest</category>
  <modificationDelaySeconds>60</modificationDelaySeconds>
  <labeller type="defaultlabeller">
     <prefix>0.1.</prefix>
     <incrementOnFailure>true</incrementOnFailure>
     <labelFormat>000</labelFormat>
  </labeller>
  <tasks>
     <exec>
        <executable>D:\MSTestExtended\Runner.exe</executable>
        <buildArgs>run-tests /project:payments /retriesCount:1</buildArgs>
        <buildTimeoutSeconds>6800</buildTimeoutSeconds>
        <successExitCodes>0</successExitCodes>
     </exec>
  </tasks>
  <publishers>
     <merge>
        <files>
           <file>D:\DEV\deploy\AutomatedTest\Results\TestPublish\BasicTests.Payments_Rerun.trx</file>
        </files>
     </merge>
     <xmllogger />
  </publishers>
```

Likewise we have many projects and then we do the build for that, but now in Jenkins I feel little lost - how do I configure it to with my according

Note: IN CCNet - it used to pick the branch whichever is checkout in VM, but I see in Jenkins we also need to manually setup the branch name; so in that case also Is there a way to specify the branch during build time?

And if I can add the selection for run-tests /project:payments /retriesCount:1 - when we initiate the jenkins build, it will aske to select the arguments

Can someone help me in that to understand the Jenkins way of doing this?

Comment: You can make use of [Jenkins Parametrized Build](https://www.baeldung.com/ops/jenkins-parameterized-builds#:~:text=A%20build%20parameter%20allows%20us,or%20pipeline%20can%20be%20parameterized.) to provide parameters before the build start.

Comment: @SouravAtta Thank you so much for suggestion, I will definitely have a look on that